# How to get an objdump without NUL bytes?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, shellcode, objdump

I have this code in assembly:

```
global _start
section .rodata
  hello: db "Hello World!", 10

section .text

_start:
    mov eax,4           
    mov ebx,1          
    mov ecx,hello       
    mov edx,13     
    int 80h             

    ; Terminate program
    mov eax,1          
    xor ebx,ebx           
    int 80h
```

If I take objdump of the following code, I get:

[image]

If I get NUL characters in the objdump I will not be able to achieve the task I'm working on. How can I get objdump without any NUL(0x00) bytes?

Comment: The file you assembled (and have at the top of your question) is not the one you objdumped.

Comment: I will assume that this is really all about shellcode exploits?

Comment: You are looking at unrelated files. It isn't even a 64-bit-assemble/32-bit-disassemble mismatch, in your source you have `syscall` while in the disassembled you have `int 80` - they are completely unrelated files.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have updated the code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes, I'm trying buffer overflow attack

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text.  Instead, copy paste the text in the image into your question.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the shellcode in this Stackoverflow answer I wrote: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50690339/3857942  . It is 64-bit code that prints a string to the console and then exits and avoids NUL bytes which is pretty much exactly what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Your title no longer matches the code. Are you trying to write 64-bit shellcode or 32-bit? 32-bit syscalls (via `int 0x80` using the stack will not work in a 64-bit exploit because the stack pointer can't be represented in 32-bits. You will need to use 64-bit syscalls in your exploit. Otherwise you will have to write shell code for 32-bit, assemble it as 32-bit and run it in a 32-bit program. Your objdump suggests you assembled with `-f elf64` and are targeting 64-bit.

Comment: With 32-bit bit code you are going to have to consider looking at alternatives like the [JMP/CALL/POP method](https://marcosvalle.github.io/osce/2018/05/06/JMP-CALL-POP-technique.html) to avoid NUL bytes when trying to use the string.

Comment: `objdump` is just a disassembler.  **It only shows the bytes that are in the file.** 
 Write asm that assembles to machine code doesn't contain any `00` bytes, then the `objdump` output will be free of them.  The most obvious one is that you have to avoid `mov r32, imm32` for small constants, because there's unfortunately no `r/m32, imm8` form of `mov`.  push imm8 / pop reg is a common workaround, or use `lea` from a known base.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to eliminate NUL(0x00) bytes in OBJDUMP you need to write shellcode that assembles into instructions that don't include NUL bytes. The methods you use are also dependent on the target. Are you writing a 32-bit exploit or a 64-bit exploit? Your current question appears to be a 32-bit exploit, so I will make that assumption.

The more complex situation in 32-bit code is getting the address of a string (that will be stack based when run as an exploit without NUL bytes). You can use the [JMP/CALL/POP method](https://marcosvalle.github.io/osce/2018/05/06/JMP-CALL-POP-technique.html) to achieve that. Alternatively You can also build the `Hello World!` string on the stack directly. I will propose a version using JMP/CALL/POP as described in the article:

**hello1.asm**:

```
global _start    
section .text

_start:
    jmp call
pop:
    pop ecx                     ; ECX = address of hello
    xor eax, eax                ; EAX = 0
    mov al, 4                   ; EAX = 4 (int 0x80 sys_write)
    xor ebx, ebx
    inc ebx                     ; EBX = 1 (1 = Standard output)
    xor edx, edx
    mov dl, hellolen            ; EDX = length of hello string
    int 0x80

    ; Terminate program
    xor eax, eax
    inc eax                     ; EAX = 1 (int 0x80 sys_exit)
    xor ebx, ebx                ; EBX = return value of 0
    int 0x80
call:
    call pop
    hello: db "Hello World!", 10
hellolen equ $-hello
```

You can assemble and link this code to a 32-bit executable called `hello1` using:

```
nasm -f elf32 hello1.asm -o hello1.o
ld -melf_i386 hello1.o -o hello1
```

The result of `objdump -D hello1` is:

> ```
> hello1:    file format elf32-i386  
>
> Disassembly of section .text:
>
> 08048060 <_start>:
>  8048060:       eb 15                   jmp    8048077 <call>
>
> 08048062 <pop>:
>  8048062:       59                      pop    %ecx
>  8048063:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
>  8048065:       b0 04                   mov    $0x4,%al
>  8048067:       31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
>  8048069:       43                      inc    %ebx
>  804806a:       31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
>  804806c:       b2 0d                   mov    $0xd,%dl
>  804806e:       cd 80                   int    $0x80
>  8048070:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
>  8048072:       40                      inc    %eax
>  8048073:       31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
>  8048075:       cd 80                   int    $0x80
>
> 08048077 <call>:
>  8048077:       e8 e6 ff ff ff          call   8048062 <pop>
>
> 0804807c <hello>:
>  804807c:       48                      dec    %eax
>  804807d:       65 6c                   gs insb (%dx),%es:(%edi)
>  804807f:       6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%edi)
>  8048080:       6f                      outsl  %ds:(%esi),(%dx)
>  8048081:       20 57 6f                and    %dl,0x6f(%edi)
>  8048084:       72 6c                   jb     80480f2 <hello+0x76>
>  8048086:       64 21 0a                and    %ecx,%fs:(%edx)
> ```

You should note that there are no NUL bytes with this code. If you run `./hello1` as a standalone program it should output:

> Hello World!

You can now convert this to a shellcode string with:

```
objcopy -Obinary hello1 shellcode.bin
hexdump -v -e '"\\""x" 1/1 "%02x" ""' shellcode.bin
```

The OBJCOPY command converts the executable to raw binary and the second outputs a string that can be used for the purposes of an exploit. The output should be:

> \xeb\x15\x59\x31\xc0\xb0\x04\x31\xdb\x43\x31\xd2\xb2\x0d\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x40\x31\xdb\xcd\x80\xe8\xe6\xff\xff\xff\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21\x0a

If you are looking for the equivalent code for 64-bit exploits you can find such an example in this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50690339/3857942).

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking your time to answer this. But there is a small problem in the shellcode generated. It has \xeb\x15\x59\x31\xc0\xb0\x04 and that's copy stops (\x04). Is there any work around for the same?.

Comment: One possible solution (haven't tested it) is, for example, to replace `mov    $0x4,%al` with `mov $69,%al ; sub $65,%al`. This would create `E` and `A` characters.

Comment: Also, inc eax is not setting eax value to 1. I connected gdb and checked and it shows eax=-4 after the increment. As inc command is not working as expected, it results in non termination of the program.

Comment: @srccode You are doing something wrong that is outside the scope of this actual question. Your issues now seem to revolve around running the code as an exploit.I recommend starting an entirely new question with your shellcode from this question, the code of the program you are trying to exploit and all the command you use to assemble/link/build and run so that someone can attempt to identify/reproduce your problem

Comment: inc al increments the value of al properly bu inc eax or inc ebx doesn't work.